# xampp apache not working err message api ms win missing

Tags: java, php, android, apache, perl

Problem detected!
Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!

```
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
Starting Check-Timer
Control Panel Ready
Problem detected!
Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
Attempting to start Apache app...
Status change detected: running
Status change detected: stopped
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
```

Comment: Something else is using your port 80, either kill the process that is using it, or go into the apache config and use a different port. ie 8080

http://localhost:8080 is then what you would use as your url.

Comment: As it is talking about something else using port 80 on **PID 4** its probably IIS and its associated parts. If you are running W10 then that is almost definitely the case.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so that means your system has Microsoft IIS installed or one of the other bits of MS technology that reports that signature, they are doing that on later versions of Windows for some reason.
If you are not intending to use it you can uninstall it, it is not an integral part of windows so its being uninstalled wont effect normal operations of windows,
and if you need to install it again later, it comes as part of the standard OS so you wont need to do anything perticularly clever.

So go to

1. Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Features
2. Click the 'Turn windows features on and off' link in the left hand
   menu.
3. Wait for the list to load and then find 'Internet Information
   Services'

Un check the check boxes for the following items ( you may not see all of them ), and there may be others I done know about. You may have all of these or just some of these.

1. IIS
2. Web Deploy 2.0 (Web Deployment Agent Service)
3. MS Sql Server Reporting service.
4. BranchCache ( Windows 8.1 )
5. SQL Server VSS Writer

[List of possible service names](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fort_sql/archive/2010/05/31/list-of-sql-server-service-names.aspx) not sure how up to date this is.

[Tutorial on how to find what ports are in use on your system and what app is using them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bgroth/archive/2004/11/11/256190.aspx)

Windows will then have a think for a while and then remove those applications, you will probably be asked to reboot to complete the uninstalls.
Reboot anyway when the uninstalls are complete.

Then try XAMPP again.

Alternativeley just disable it/them.

```
Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services
```

Find IIS in the list of services.
Left Click that line and select Properties

Comment: sir still facing same problem i have made all changes as you have mentioned  above . I am getting same error .