# Removing IIS to make wampserver run normally

Tags: windows, iis, wamp, iis-7.5, wampserver

I am installing a web app for my client, and he want to work only locally with it.

I had a problem making the wamp server to online. I checked the port 80, and it was used by `IIS`.

I tried to stop by running `services.msc` and set its start to manual. And still got the same problem. Then I tried [solutions from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621592/cant-use-wamp-port-80-is-used-by-iis-7-5), where I used the cmd to stop it:`iisreset /stop` but it will stop for only one session if I can say that, so after restart, it will run again.

Then I went to httpd.conf and change the following line:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

Into:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
```

So wamp now will listen to a different port than 80.

Skype is not installed on his laptop.

It seems to be working, but now he called me and told me that he have the same problem. I checked it, and Yeah, IIS again.

He will ask for refund in couple of days, if I didn't fix it once for all. Yeah, he said that. And still can't figure it out.

Is it okay, if I uninstalled IIS from his laptop ? He don't use it anyway, but he is a doctor and he have an `X-ray` program, and I don't know if IIS is used by this software.

Comment: Have you had a look on this link? http://serverfault.com/questions/325224/how-do-i-stop-iis7-5-starting-by-default

Comment: I disabled `World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC)` but I didn't take attention to `IIS Admin Service (IISADMIN)`, mostly i didn't see it in `services.msc`

Comment: Is [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220041/xampp-apache-not-working-err-message-api-ms-win-missing/35220459#35220459) any use to you. Ignore that its about XAMPP, they are pretty similiar

Comment: It may helps me. I will go for a meeting with him in couple of hours, and I will try all of your posted link.