# i change the "Listen 80" line to "Listen 8080" in config apache but still it doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, xampp

my apache is ok but when i update my php,Apache will not start and xampp say "Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!"  and i change the "Listen 80" line to "Listen 8080" in config apache but apache say yet "Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!"

Comment: Have you tried turning your computer of and on again?

Comment: You have to restart the apache server

Comment: Sounds like you have IIS running, that is also a web server so will capture port 80.. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220041/xampp-apache-not-working-err-message-api-ms-win-missing/35220459#35220459

Answer (score 0):

Reverse whatever you've done and go to xampp folder and search for xampp-control.ini

Look for `[ServicePorts]` and change the line below it to `Apache=8080`